# Obiee 12c DENSE_RANK function

Tags: obiee, dense-rank

I would like to know if it is possible to execute the **dense_rank** function in **OBIEE12c** in another way (for example mathematically), this is because to execute the **dense_rank** I need to add configs on the server and I don't have access to it.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you really need to add some sample data here.  Yes, dense rank can possibly be simulated, but any answer would depend on your actual data.

Comment: I have a "Group Number" with numbers that are randomly assigned, within this Group I have "departments", I want to give sequential numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...) to the groups and associate only the group number in all departments in that group, the rank function jumps numbers depending on which departments we have, can you understand? Thanks!

Comment: Great, you're almost there.  Now just add a table of this sample data to your question.

Comment: I have something like this: "Group Number: 2, 10, 5, 300 | Department: A, B C D, E F, G".
I want a column with: ""POSITION": 1, 2 2 2, 3 3, 4" without using the dense_rank. Thanks!